# Proving that Mx is an eigenvector of B with λ as the eigenvalue given that $B=MAM^{-1}$ and $Ax=λx$

Tags: linear-algebra

> The square matrix A has λ as an eigenvalue with corresponding eigenvector x. The non-singular matrix M is of the same order as A. Show that Mx is an eigenvector of the matrix B, where $B = MAM^{−1}$, and that λ is the corresponding eigenvalue.

Here is How I started:

$$Ax=λx$$

$$BM=MAM^{-1}M$$

$$BM= MA$$

$$BM= Mλx$$

Something is not right. Can someone shed some light? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

$$B(Mx)=(BM)x=(MA)x=M(Ax)=M(\lambda x)=\lambda(Mx)$$
hence the desired result.

Comment: Thank You alottt :D How are you so smart? :)